# Why do (1 && !A) in c++ pre-processor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In some C++ file, I found:

```cpp
#ifndef UE_WITH_CHEAT_MANAGER
#define UE_WITH_CHEAT_MANAGER (1 && !UE_BUILD_SHIPPING)
#endif
```

Comming from CheatManager.h.

What is the difference with:

```cpp
#ifndef UE_WITH_CHEAT_MANAGER
#define UE_WITH_CHEAT_MANAGER (!UE_BUILD_SHIPPING)
#endif
```

Is it in order to prevent warnings on some specific compiler?

Additional info:

- `UE_BUILD_SHIPPING` is 0 by default and is set to 1 for shipping builds (builds that are distributed to consumers/players).
- `UE_WITH_CHEAT_MANAGER` is used to exclude some part of the code from compilation.

(Edited to answer requests in comments.)

Comment: Try using `A("frog")` and see what happens.  The `1 && !B` is looking for a numeric expression.  The `(!B)` expression will give undefined values for non-numeric types.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `!"frog"` is valid, right?  It's testing whether `"frog"` is a null pointer, and it never is, so `!"frog"` evaluates to `0`.  So does `1 && !"frog"`, so I don't see any difference between the two here.

Comment: They could of course be different if the `!` and `&&` operators were overloaded.

Comment: It depends on the context of `A` whether or not the macro is useful. It might be useful to be able to modify a bunch of tests to evaluate to `false` from a single macro, for example.

Comment: Can you give an indication of how this macro is used in the code? Do you have a link to the file it exists in in the unreal engine?

Comment: Can you post the exact code from the unreal engine, before you simplified? Might be something in there that was relevant?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to indicate in the initial post that `B` was a macro with value 0 or 1. I hope this is better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is perfect, not even the authors of the Unreal Engine.

Setting aside any possibility of operator overloading, the type and values of the two expressions are identical. I *suspect* (and it's only a hunch), that the author is forgetting that the type of `(!B)` is a `bool` in C++.

`(1 && !B)` is more explicitly perhaps a `bool` type as it contains the `&&` operator.

Comment: If `B` is a class with an overloaded `operator!` then this can return any type, so in that case they are different. its a pretty niche scenario tho.